# Is there anything like 'getStreamsToHost' on real iPhone device?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, stream

I want to write an NSOutputStream to a server with apple's sample code:

```
NSURL *website = [NSURL URLWithString:str_IP];
NSHost *host = [NSHost hostWithName:[website host]];
[NSStream getStreamsToHost:host port:1100 inputStream:nil outputStream:&oStream];
[oStream retain];
[oStream setDelegate:self];
[oStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[oStream open];
```

These codes works well on the iPhone simulator, but when I build it to real device. Two warnings pop up. The problem is:

1)class NSHost doesn't belong to iphone os library

2)getStreamsToHost is not found either

Any suggestions for the alternative method or class which can be used on real device?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since CFWriteStream is [toll-free bridged](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/CocoaStreamsOverview.html) to NSOutputStream you can use CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost to get your stream pair:

```
CFReadStreamRef readStream = NULL;
CFWriteStreamRef writeStream = NULL;
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)host, port, &readStream, &writeStream);
if (readStream && writeStream) {
    CFReadStreamSetProperty(readStream, kCFStreamPropertyShouldCloseNativeSocket, kCFBooleanTrue);
    CFWriteStreamSetProperty(writeStream, kCFStreamPropertyShouldCloseNativeSocket, kCFBooleanTrue);

    inputStream = (NSInputStream *)readStream;
    [inputStream retain];
    [inputStream setDelegate:self];
    [inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [inputStream open];

    outputStream = (NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
    [outputStream retain];
    [outputStream setDelegate:self];
    [outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [outputStream open];
}

if (readStream)
    CFRelease(readStream);

if (writeStream)
    CFRelease(writeStream);
```

Comment: Thanks. And one more question:'kCFStreamPropertyShouldCloseNativeSocket' cannot be found either. Should I use 'kCFStreamPropertySocketNativeHandle' instead or just don't set property for CFWriteStream?

Comment: It's there, you may need to #include <CFNetwork/CFSocketStream.h>

Comment: Here is [implemented category](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1652/_index.html) by apple.